# How to make index visible/Invisible at runtime

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Oracle 11g has a feature in which we can make an index visible/invisible. I was recently asked in an interview about how to make index invisible/visible at run-time, how is that possible?

Comment: I've tried to improved the wording to the question

Answer (score 1):

create invisible index :
        `SQL > create index tst_invisble_idx on Employee(emp_name) invisible;`

you can alter index to visible : `SQL > alter index tst_invisble_idx visible;`

you can alter index to invisible again : `SQL > alter index tst_invisble_idx invisible;`

to make all indexes invisible to the optimizer for users : `SQL> alter system set optimizer_user_invisible_indexes=true;`

to show index invisible status : `SQL>    show paramter invisible;`

Hope this helps :)